# Dados cadastrados desaparecem

Tags: vb.net

O formulário de Cadastro cadastra corretamente no banco de dados e se trocar usuario com o programa aberto ele ainda acessa os dados cadastrados, mas quanto fecha completamente o programa e abre denovo todos o dados cadastrados somem alguem sabe o que pode ser isso?
obs - codigo abaixo

```
 Private Sub Salva()

    Using con As OleDbConnection = GetConnection()

        Try

            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO usuarios (login,senha,perfil) VALUES(?,?,?)"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@login", TextBox1.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@senha", TextBox2.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@perfil", ComboBox1.SelectedIndex))

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Usuário Cadastrado Com Sucesso!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar gravar um novo Usuário", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        Finally

            con.Close()

        End Try

    End Using

    LimpaCampos()

End Sub
```

Comment: Você está commitando as transações?

Comment: Você consegue visualizar estes dados no banco de dados (fora da aplicação)? Não há uma transação com commit pendente no seu programa? Se a última resposta for SIM provavelmente este seja o problema.

Comment: sim nao estou usando commit sou meio novato nesse lance de banco de dados mas quando a aplicacao esta aberta os dados aparecem no banco sim

Comment: Se aparece fora do seu programa mesmo enquanto a aplicação está aberta então não é um problema de transação. A transação restringiria os dados visíveis a sua aplicação. É necessário verificar mais detalhes do seu código que façam alguma interação com o BD para podermos chegar a alguma conclusão. Infelizmente não tenho como testar seu código no momento.